# protect form hijacking hack

Tags: php, html, csrf-protection

Yes hello today I discovered a hack for my site.

When you write a msg on a users wall (in my communitysite) it runs a ajax call, to insert the msg to the db and will then on success slide down and show it.

Works fine with no problem.

So I was rethinking alittle, I am using POST methods for this and if it was  GET method you could easily do ?msg=haxmsg&usr=12345679. But what could you do to come around the POST method?

I made a new html document, made a form and on action i set "site.com/insertwall.php" (the file that normally are being used in ajax), i made some input fields with names exactly like i am doing with the ajaxcall (msg, uID (userid), BuID (by userid)  ) and made a submit button.

I know I have a page_protect() function on which requires you to login and if you arent you will be header to index.php. So i logged in (started session on my site.com) and then I pressed on this submit button. And then wops I saw on my site that it has made a new message.

I was like wow, was it so easy to hijack POST method i thought maybe it was little more secure or something.

I would like to know what could I do to prevent this hijacking? As i wouldnt even want to know what real hackers could do with this "hole". The page_protect secures that the sessions are from the same http user agent and so, and this works fine (tried to run the form without logging in, and it just headers me to startpage) but yea wouldnt take long time to figure out to log in first and then run it.

Any advices are appreciated alot. I would like to keep my ajax calls most secure as possible and all of them are running on the POST method. What could I do to the insertwall.php, to check that it comes from the server or something..

Thank you

Comment: Why does it need `?msg=haxmsg&usr=12345679`? Don't you have a session based user login that you can get the user ID from?

Comment: I'm trying to see what the problem is. It would appear that you are concerned that a user, given permission to send a message, is able to send a message.

Comment: @Pekka that is true sorry, bad example. But what I want to archieve is not to make it able to write the message by a form you make yourself or in a ?msg=.....

Comment: @DavidDorward I am concerned that a user can do malicious stuff by sending a message from another way. I am not only concerned for the messages but the other ajax calls also im having.

Comment: I think you are lost. A message is always written "from another place than the server". It is posted from a browser. If a user who is logged in writes his own form that posts to your page (assuming that anyone would want to do that) what would the problem be? You can always check the HTTP_REFERER parameter to check for this if you want to prevent it, but you have not discovered a major security issue with your site, you have merely discovered an issue with your own understanding of the interaction between browsers and a web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment…

Anything outside your server is outside your control. You must define what you want to let in at the border of your server, and not in the browser.

So, for example, if you want to let people send messages, then any restrictions you want to impose (only logged in users, only to friends, only when the moon is waxing, etc) must be imposed on the server.

What you send to the browser can be thought of as an application that interacts with your API. People might interact with your API in ways that you don't expect, but you are safe if all your security is taken care of by the server.

(Until we come onto the subject of man in the middle stuff, in which case look into [CSRF prevention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) and encryption with SSL)

Answer (score 4):

This vulnerability is called as Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF).
You must add a random token value in your form (input hidden).
`$_SESSION['token'] = md5(rand()); //example
//ur code
if($_SESSION["token"] != $_POST["token"]){
    echo 'Invalid Request!';
}
else{
    //action
}`